# Why does the node drawn by this code not have borders around it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm trying to draw a simple ER-diagram. However, the following code does not produce borders around nodes:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, positioning, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
  \ttfamily
  \begin{tikzpicture}[draw=black, thick, ->, >=stealth,
    entity/.style={ellipse, text centered}
    field/.style={rectangle, text centered}
    relation/.style={diamond, text centered}
    ]

    \node (pilot) [entity] {Pilot};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Adding `draw=black` to the styles does not help. Only by specifying `draw` in the node options themselves, as in

```
\node (pilot) [draw] {Pilot};
```

works. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodes do not automatically inherit every key put into the global options. The manual (around page 128) says that the correct way to give global options is to use the `every...` keys. For example using in the options

```
every node/.style={draw=black, thick},
```

will do what you want.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, positioning, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
  \ttfamily
  \begin{tikzpicture}[draw=black, thick, ->, >=stealth, red,
    every node/.style={draw=black, thick},
    entity/.style={ellipse, text centered}
    field/.style={rectangle, text centered}
    relation/.style={diamond, text centered}
    ]
    \node (pilot) [entity] {Pilot};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output for the snippet above]